# Meteor app cannot start up after installing Crypto-sha1 package with meteorite

Tags: meteor, package, meteorite

I installed the crypto-sha1 package with meteorite. Now when I start up the app,
the following error shows up:

```
Your app is crashing. Here's the latest log.


/Users/ian/myapp/queue4me/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:186
}).run();
   ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'lib' of undefined
    at Package (packages/crypto-sha1/sha1.js:10)
    at Package (packages/crypto-sha1/sha1.js:136)
    at packages/crypto-sha1.js:154:4
    at packages/crypto-sha1.js:161:3
    at /Users/ian/myapp/queue4me/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:155:10
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Function._.each._.forEach 
   (/Users/ian/.meteor/tools/5bf1690853/lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
    at /Users/ian/myapp/queue4me/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:82:5 
=> Exited with code: 8
=> Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

The package requires `CryptoJS` too as a dependency. So you also have to add https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/crypto-base.

Usually meteorite does this for you, make sure you have the latest version of meteorite with `sudo -H npm install -g meteorite`

Comment: Yes, I figured it out myself - I manually added cryto-base in smart.json file, then now it is fine. However, why meteorite install the dependent package for me but not defining it in the smart.json file?? Tricky.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, You have to manually added the dependent package in smart.json by yourself.